# Creating a Calculated Date Field with embedded double quotes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, calculated-column, spfield

I have been provisioning a load of Site Colummns with PowerShell . I am however, having a lot grief with a calculated field

```
 spField.Formula = "=TEXT(DATE([Created],"mmyyyy"))"
 spField.OutputType = "Text"
```

THis updates and even appears in the SIte Columns gallery but it is unusable

I think the embedded quotes is the issue and I have tried

- "" using double quotes
- `"
- `"

But each time my site column formula syntax gives an update at runtime.

Daniel

Comment: Did you try making the inner double quotes single quotes? "=TEXT(DATE([Created],'mmyyyy'))"

Comment: @PirateEric I am pretty sure I had tried that. So I deleted my test site col . recreated as you suggested. Try to add I get The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

Comment: Yes, single quotes are not valid in formulas. But whats with \"?

Comment: @Fensterbank .. I actually found the back \'" in a blog post .. today I had another google and this looks promising[link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/28/writing-double-quotation-marks-to-a-text-file-using-windows-powershell.aspx)

Comment: I think I have cracked it but be good for others to verify      $spField.Formula = "TEXT([Created], $([char]34)mmYYYY$([char]34))"